# Validity of Elastic collision approximation

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws, collision

> For elastic collisions, if the mass m1 is much much greater than m2,
> the velocity of m1 during the collision remains unchanged while the
> velocity of m2 can easily be found by Relative velocity of
> separation=(-)velocity of approach.

Heres the problem. Suppose that m1 and m2 are moving toward each other with equal but opposite momenta and m1>>>m2. V2, then, is much much greater than V1. The total linear momentum of the system will remain 0 at all times. By the approximation mentioned above, m1 would continue to move with its velocity unchanged, and if m1 is perfectly rigid, m2 must start moving in the same direction. But this contradicts the law of conservation of linear momentum, which is now non 0.

Is the approximation even valid in this case? Is linear momentum of the smaller mass implicitly assumed to be less than that of the larger mass? Can someone give a better view of the situation

Comment: V1, then, is much much greater than m2  what does this mean

Comment: This is just an approximation which tries to convey the idea that if you throw a ping pong ball to a truck coming towards you then you should pretty much expect that after collision the speed of the truck will not change and the ball will come back to you with the same speed you threw. Like any other approximations this one has corner cases. Can one stop a truck by throwing a ping pong ball? In principle, yes, in practice, very unlikely.

Comment: Just to be clear, I should implicitly assume/check that the situation is not extreme to make the approximation?

Comment: Please go to the wikipedia page about collisions (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_collision) and scroll down to the part "One-dimensional Newtonian". Over there there is a short video of Walter Lewin talking about exactly this approximation. I think it will make things clearer.

Answer (score 1):

It's a pretty good approximation, is it not, for a 'super-ball' hitting a concrete floor or a molecule hitting the wall of a vessel? The far greater mass of the Earth and the vessel make their post-collision velocities utterly negligible even though they acquire roughly twice the momentum of the incident ball or molecule.

So if the rule you have quoted is *billed as* an approximation, it's fine. All the same, I'd have put in another 'approximately' between 'remains' and 'unchanged'.

Comment: It’s perfectly reasonable for a ball hitting the earth, or a moving cycle hitting a moving truck. But what about the case i have mentioned where the total linear momentum of the system before the collision is 0. I find it very hard to understand how the approximation is still reasonable

Comment: My examples will serve your purpose. Take the case of the Earth (mass *M*) and the ball (mass *m*, initial velocity $\vec u$). View the collision in the *centre of mass* frame of reference, that is a frame moving with velocity $m \vec u / (m+M)$ with respect to the Earth. In this new frame of reference the ball and the earth have equal and opposite momenta!

Comment: In the com frame of your earth-ballexample, the heavy mass is effectively stationary so it can obtain a. Backward momentum whilst still being effectively stationary, which makes the approximation reasonably. How would you explain the reasonableness of the approximation when the heavy mass is moving at a non negligible velocity in the com frame?

Comment: Because ≫ the large mass  can't be moving fast in the centre of mass frame! The large mass of $M$ dictates that the CoM frame is very nearly the frame in which $M$ is stationary.

Comment: No, but in my example, V of the smaller mass is very large(so that its momentum is equal and oppsite) so M can be large, just not in your example which you have decided not not to reconsider.

Comment: No decision was taken by me not to reconsider anything. And I'm afraid that I don't understand the rest of your comment. Put it down to my stupidity.